# click works with jQuery but not vanilla js

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I use jQuery and click on the icon it works fine:

```
   $(document).on('click', '.fileuploader-action-sort', function() {
         alert('clicked');
    });
```

But if I use vanilla js, I have to literally click at the very bottom of the icon, like on the tip for it to actually work otherwise nothing happens when clicking anywhere else on the actual icon.

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", e => {
        if (!e.target.matches(".fileuploader-action-sort")) return;
        alert('clicked');
    });
```

Here is the html:

```
<a class="fileuploader-action fileuploader-action-sort" title="Sort"><i></i></a>
```

I am generating the icons based on the number of database records I have which is why I didn't use `document.querySelector('.fileuploader-action-sort');`

Comment: Note that the code snippets you posted are not logically equivalent.

Comment: the problem is that `e.target` is `i` not `a` you need to check `if (!e.target.matches(".fileuploader-action-sort i")) return;`

Comment: @jcubic, thanks for that, it works. I had tried `a.fileuploader-action-sort` but your way makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `e.target` refers to the whole document in your vanilla js example if you click on the div, and it refers to the `i` tag if you click on any content inside of it. But in the jQuery example it refers to the `.fileuploader-action-sort` class.

One way to notice it is to `console.log(e.target)` :

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", e => {
  console.log(e.target)
  if (!e.target.matches(".fileuploader-action-sort")) return;
  alert('clicked');
});
```

```html
<a class="fileuploader-action fileuploader-action-sort" title="Sort"><i>Test</i></a>
```

So you need to listen to the `i` tag and not the class in itself :

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (!e.target.matches(".fileuploader-action-sort i")) return;
  alert('clicked');
});
```

```html
<a class="fileuploader-action fileuploader-action-sort" title="Sort"><i>Test</i></a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I appreciate it.

Comment: @user8463989 happy to help :-)